# Ajax get request failing on json

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to get a products title via json in an ajax get request. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/products/test-product.js',
  success: function(result) {
      var obj2 = JSON.parse(result2);
      console.log(obj2);
                var test2= obj2.title ;
    },
    error: function(status) {
        console.warn('ERROR', status);
    }
})
```

However, this keeps failing. The error status looks something like this:

```
abort: ƒ (a)
always: ƒ ()
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
error: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (a)
readyState: 4
responseText: "{"id":96086,"title":"Test Product"
setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)
state: ƒ ()
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ (a)
statusText: "OK"
success: ƒ ()
then: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

Anybody got any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The request itself seems to have gone through OK (`status: 200` and `responseText` contains valid JSON). Here's a wild guess: I notice that your endpoint has a `.js` extension -- could it be that your Web server is sending the wrong MIME-Type, and therefore jQuery is refusing to parse it? Try changing your endpoint's filename to `.json` instead.

Comment: Also try `console.log(status.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"))`

Comment: @PedroLM that was it, thanks!